# Searching a hashmap using a jtextfield and jbutton

Tags: java

I'm having some trouble getting a search to work correctly. The first thing I'm doing is adding 2 values from 2 separate jtextfields and adding one to key and one to value of a hashmap. This also adds the value to a jlist.

The second is a jtextfield and jbutton that is supposed to search for the key and highlight it's corresponding value in the jlist field.

For the first button's action performed ( the one that adds the value/key  ) I have the following code:

if (capitalText.getText().equals("")) {
            capitalText.requestFocusInWindow();

```
    } else if (countryText.getText().equals("")) {
         countryText.requestFocusInWindow();

    } else {
        lm.addElement(capitalText.getText());
        capitalText.setText(value);
        countryText.setText(key);

        String key=countryText.getText();
        String value=capitalText.getText();

        hashMap.put(key,value);
        searchButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

For the search button I have the following code:

String value=hashMap.get(key);
        searchText.setText(search);

```
    if(searchText.getText().equals(key))  {
       searchText.setText(search);
       String search = (String) jList1.getSelectedValue();
   } else {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"That search term could not be found","Search Inquiry",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
   }
```

It appears to add and set the value/key, but when I attempt to search it always does the "else" statement and throws the joptionpane.

Are the value/key actually being added correctly? Or is the search not working? Or both?

Thank you for any advice/help!!

Comment: `it always does the "else" statement` - did you add a System.out.println(..) statement to your code to see what the two values are that you are comparing? If you understand why they are different you should be able to fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you, sometimes I over think things too much, discovered a problem and it is now adding to the hashmap, just the searching isn't work